# PHP: Can't assign a constant in a function?

Tags: php

I have a function called getSources(); In this function I want to easily assign numbers to constants. I figured this would work:

```
const A = 1;
const B = 2;
const C = 3;
const D = 4;
```

And I could just do this:

```
$someValue = A;
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing? I don't want these variables to be used outside of the scope of this function.

Comment: have you tried using `define()`..?

Comment: A constant is not a variable and you can't limit their scope to a function. They are always in global scope, no matter where you define them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use define instead.

```
define('A', 1);
```

Comment: But is this global? Or will it only be accessible in the function?

Comment: Global course.. Did your read documentation about [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
define('myname', 'myvalue');
echo myname;
```

// Output

```
myvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the scope resolution operator (`::`) to access them (if they're setup as `const` for a class).

Otherwise, you need to use `define()` which makes the identifiers global.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
function getSources()
{
    define(A,1);
    define(B,2);
    ....
 }
```

like this you can solve it